# What about uart1 pins on esp8266 micropython?

Tags: esp8266, micropython

I'm totally confused on esp8266 micropython for uart1,
The rx and tx pins in uart1
are one of which pins are 2 and 8 or 8 and 7?

Comment: Have you just tried? It's really easy to experiment and figure out the answer to this.

Comment: My code is like this:
from machine import UART
uart = UART(1, baudrate=9600)
uart.read()
And the pins are as follows:
rx: D8
tx: D2
But when I run the code, it gives me an error:
UART(1) can't read

Comment: Is it possible to change the rx and tx bases in uart esp8266 micropython?

Comment: The second UART can only transmit, not receive. There is no RX pin for it.